# How do I connect to Heroku Postgres from Nest.js?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, nestjs, heroku-postgres

When running `heroku config` I see (with some omissions)

```
DATABASE_URL: postgres://<xxxx>:<xxxx>@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dm74hmu71b97n
```

which I know is of form `postgres://<user>:<password>@<hostname>:<port>/<database>`. But right now in my Nest.JS app I connect to postgres like this:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            inject: [ConfigService],
            useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                type: 'postgres',
                host: configService.get('POSTGRES_HOST'),
                port: configService.get('POSTGRES_PORT'),
                username: configService.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
                password: configService.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
                database: configService.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
                entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
                synchronize: false,
            }),
        }),
    ],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

I suppose I could manually parse `process.env.DATABASE_URL` I figured there must be a better/easier way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    url: configService.get('DATABASE_URL'),
    type: 'postgres',
    entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    synchronize: false,
}),
```